# Set width of <td> to <th> dynamically

Tags: jquery, css

I am wondering how to get the width of a `th` and set all of the `td` under this header to be the same width. Next `th` would be a different width and all of the `td` under this `th` would be that appropriate width, different from the first. Essentially trying to line up my `thead` and `tbody` columns relative to eachother.

The structure of my table is:

```
<table id="my_table">
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

The CSS is as follows for a scroll able table:

```
#my_table thead, #my_table tbody {
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #my_table thead{
        height: 100px;
    }

    #my_table tbody{
        height: 300px;
    }
```

The data that goes into th is dynamic and makes the width of the cell different every time.

Using jQuery, I am stuck with this not sure how to iterate through each `th` and assign the width to its corresponding `td`:

```
var table = document.getElementById('#my_table');

table.find('th').each(function() {
    var header_width = this.width();
    $table.width(header_width);
});
```

Although this is not working. I feel as if I am using the `each()` function incorrectly. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the row height fixed or dynamic?

Comment: Row height will always be fixed.

Comment: If the row height is fixed, you can use CSS-only flexbox to achieve this without using jQuery, although your html has to be changed.

Comment: Please see edits, using an inline-block because I need the thead static while tbody is scroll able

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st. sum the `th` length first (by letter length), then update the width by `%` of `th` length, see example below:
2nd. wrap your content with `<div class="scrollable">` and css:

```
.scrollable{
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

This allowed you to control the height of the `td` without set tbody to inline block which breaks the layout.

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  var total_len = $('thead tr th').text().length;
  $('thead tr th').each(function() {
    pct = $(this).text().length / total_len * 100;
    $(this).width(pct + '%');
  })
}).trigger('resize');
```

```css
table * {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

table * {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

#my_table thead tr {
  height: 100px;
}

.scrollable{
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>111 121312312 21 1211 31123121</th>
      <th>2222 2 22 22</th>
      <th>3333 </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="scrollable">tests 11 1 1 1 1 1 111 1 1 1 1 1</div></td>
      <td><div class="scrollable">2 2 2 22 2</div></td>
      <td><div class="scrollable">I am wondering how to get the width of a th and set all of the td under this header to be the same width. Next th would be a different width and all of the td under this th would be that appropriate width, different from the first. Essentially trying
        to line up my thead and tbody columns relative to eachother.</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Not really. Change the content of the third column second row, to be large. It will push the whole column. That is not intended. The intended behavior is to have the width defined by the `th`, not by the cell itself.

Comment: @lilezek updated too, for the fixed height, using a div wrapper with css.

Comment: @nyvokub updated, for the fixed height, using a div wrapper with css.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, is ugly and is not efficient but should do what you want to do:

```
var table = document.getElementById('#my_table');

table.find('th').each(function(index) {
    var header_width = this.width();
    table.find('tr').each(function() {
      $(this).find('td:nth-child('+index+')').width(header_width);
    });
});
```

Note: I didn't check the syntax, so it may contain a bug.

Comment: Syntax looks good and I see your logic although no effect on my table when I run it.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm can't check it for you right now. Just wanted to give a quick solution. I'll delete this answer if it is not working when I get to a computer. The idea here is to use nth-child selector to set the width with the correct index of every tr.

Answer (score -1):

Just change each th width to a fixed width with css:

```css
#my-table th,
#my-table tbody td {
    border-width: 0 1px 0 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
}

#my-table th:first-child {
    width: 20%;
}

#my-table th:nth-child(2) {
    width: 30%;
}

#my-table th:nth-child(3) {
    width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<table id="my-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>COLUMN 1 Title</th>
      <th>COLUMN 2 Title</th>
      <th>COLUMN 3 Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Dolor sit ames</td>
      <td>Random Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>More random text</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Dolor sit ames</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

P.S. Add max-width instead of width to allow them to expand (as much as possible)

Comment: `The data that goes into th is dynamic and makes the width of the cell different every time.` That is not compatible with giving the th a fixed width.

Comment: This will not work because the number of th will not always be 3, this was used as an example. The number of th can range from 3-20+ in my case being dynamic so fixed widths will break my table.

Comment: oh sorry, then i have to agree with @lilezek answer.